# sql query to find unique combination of column data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write sql query that will select distinct combination of columns from a table.

**Example table data:**

```
+--+---+---+---+
|id|fk1|fk2|fk3|
+--+---+---+---+
|1 |1  |2  |3  |
+--+---+---+---+
|2 |1  |3  |3  |
+--+---+---+---+
|3 |2  |2  |3  |
+--+---+---+---+
|4 |2  |4  |3  |
+--+---+---+---+
|5 |3  |2  |3  |
+--+---+---+---+
|6 |3  |3  |3  |
+--+---+---+---+
|7 |3  |4  |3  |
+--+---+---+---+
```

Here I need to write a query that will return `fk1 => 2` as it has unique combination of `fk2  => 2 and 4`

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: Why is "2" a unique combination but not "1"?  Both intersect fully with "3".

Comment: because i am looking for row with combination of fk2 => 2 and 4

Comment: You are looking for row with fk2 => 2 or fk2 => 4? Or do you mean you need all rows with fk2 = 2 and fk2 = 4?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav fk2 => 2 and 4 are the input to the query. and the outputh should be fk1 => 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see.  The values "2" and "4" are inputs into the query and you want exactly that combination.  This is a set-within-sets query, and I think aggregation with a `having` clause is the most flexible approach.

```
select fk1
from table t
group by fk1
having sum(fk2 = 2) > 0 and
       sum(fk2 = 4) > 0 and
       sum(fk2 not in (2, 4)) = 0;
```

That is, the key `fk1` has the value of `2` (at least once), has the value of `4`, and has no other values.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, Your assumption is correct. But I just tried it and for me it returned nothing. Also the explanation of what query does would help in future. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a SQL Fiddle that demonstrates that it works (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90ace/1).

Comment: thanks. It does work. I had some issue with the quotes.

Comment: Would be very helpful if you could explain `sum(fk2 = 2) > 0` what that does.

Comment: @Subash . . . That is MySQL syntax for counting the number of rows that have `fk2` with a value of `2`.

Comment: that makes sense. and what does this do `sum(fk2 not in (2, 4)) = 0`?

Comment: That counts the number of rows that have values other than 2 or 4.  Only `fk1` values that have no such rows pass.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It does makes all sense to me now.